# JS: What is the best way to handle reading an attribute that is not directly set?

Tags: javascript

If I am adding an event listener to an element that as a font size that isn't directly defined, what's the best way to increment that on click?

For example `event.target.style.fontSize` is equal to "" when trying to read it and increment it.

```
  cont.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let size = parseInt(event.target.style.fontSize.split("px")[0]) + 5;
    event.target.style.fontSize = fontSize.toString() + "px"

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `window.getComputedStyle`:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

> The computed style is the style actually used in displaying the element, after "stylings" from multiple sources have been applied. Style sources can include: internal style sheets, external style sheets, inherited styles and browser default styles.